# Match an argument's attribute value in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, matcher

Is there a way to match an argument's attribute *value* in rspec? Checking [the documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/method-stubs) it looks like there's other matchers available, such as `anything`, `an_instance_of`, and `hash_including` - but nothing to check the value of an object's attribute.

Example - suppose I have this instance method:

```
class DateParser
  def parse_year(a_date)
    puts a_date.year
  end
end
```

Then I can write an expectation like this:

```
dp = DateParser.new
expect(dp).to receive(:parse_year).with(some_matcher)
```

What I want for `some_matcher` to check that `parse_year` is called with any object that has an attribute `year` that has the value 2014. Is this possible with the out-of-the-box argument matchers in rspec, or does a custom one have to be written?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass a block and set expectations about the argument(s) within the block:

```
describe DateParser do
  it "expects a date with year 2014" do
    expect(subject).to receive(:parse_year) do |date|
      expect(date.year).to eq(2014)
    end
    subject.parse_year(Date.new(2014,1,1))
  end
end
```

Comment: Where this "block" form came from ? I can't find on documentation https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments

Comment: @duleorlovic see [Use a block to verify arguments](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-6/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation#use-a-block-to-verify-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something using a double for the passed-in date?

```
date = double()
date.should_receive(:year)
DateParser.new.parse_year(date)
```

It's not clear what you mean by the date needing to be 2014.  But you could add `.and_return(2014)` to it to get that behavior from the double.

Comment: I need to test that the argument passed, `date` in your example, both responds to `:year` *and* that the value of `date.year` is 2014. In my particular example, I can't mock an object that returns a stubbed value for year, as you've suggested.